# Is Clark's Futures calculation incorrect?

Tags: futures, forward, discounting

I was working through Clark's Commodity option pricing: A practitioner's guide published 2014, and when I get to the Futures case study section 2.3.3, the answers I get differs from his (I tried to find the errata for the book but it doesn't seem to exist).

**Summary of problems**

1. Some of his P/L calculations are incorrect.
2. I think our discount factors we calculated differ, which is why our forward and futures PV differ. If my discount factor is incorrect I don't know why.

**Explanation**

He considers a WTI contract on NYMEX. He considers two short positions entered into on 21st Oct 2010 a forward contract and a DEC10 futures with strike $K=85$ and US interest rate $r=0.0025$ (0.25%). He states the initial margin as $9.788\text{USD}$ and variation margin as $7.25\text{USD}$. He obtains the following table

[image]

Working through the same example I acquire the following table:

[image]

Where the yellow highlighted cells are the P/L values which are different from Clark's - is this a mistake on my part or his? The last column is the cashflows for the futures contract.

The second potential problem is when he PV's the cashflows. He states the PVs as:

- forward PV = $3.48931\text{USD}$;
- futures PV = $3.48954\text{USD}$.

Summing the cashflows in the last column in my spreadsheet gives $3.493\text{USD}$ which is different from his undercounted forward. Calculating the PV for the forward gives:
$$F(t_0, T)=\mathrm{e}^{-r\cdot (T-t_0)}\text{cashflow on last day}=\mathrm{e}^{0.0025 \cdot (19Nov2010 - 21Oct2010)}\cdot 3.493=\mathrm{e}^{0.0025\cdot \text{30 days in years}}\cdot 3.493=\mathrm{e}^{0.0025\cdot 0.0821372}\cdot 3.493=3.492283\text{USD},$$

where 30 days in seconds is $30 \cdot 24\cdot 3600$ and therefore 30 days in years = $\frac{30 \cdot 24\cdot 3600}{31,556,952}=0.0821372.$

I fear that it is my discount calculation which is incorrect. Discounting his forward value using my discount factor I get $3.489283\text{USD}$, which does not match his ($3.48931\text{USD}$). The closest I get to his calculation is to assume that the discounting starts at the end of the first day, i.e., $T-t_1 = 29 days = 0.0793993$ which gives a value of $3.489307\text{USD}$. This seems strange to me since I would have thought it would be $T-t_0$.

A similar thing happens when calculating the PV of the futures contract:

Discounting the futures cashflows I get

$f(t_0, T) = \mathrm{e}^{-0.0025\cdot (19Nov2010 - 20Oct2020)}\cdot(-9.788) + \mathrm{e}^{-0.0025\cdot(19Nov2010-10Nov2010)}\cdot (-0.260)+\mathrm{e}^{-0.0025\cdot (19Nov2010 - 11Nov2010)}\cdot(-0.01)+13.551=\mathrm{e}^{-0.0025\cdot 0.0821372}\cdot(-9.788)+ \mathrm{e}^{-0.0025\cdot 0.024641}\cdot (-0.260)+\mathrm{e}^{-0.0025\cdot 0.021903}\cdot(-0.01)+13.551=-9.767922-0.259840-0.009995+13.551=3.512570\text{USD}.$

Which again does not equal Clark's ($3.48954\text{USD}$). Reading on he states a discount factor of 2.5% so I would not be surprised that he is incorrect. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The only question seems "Where the yellow highlighted cells are the P/L values which are different from Clark's - is this a mistake on my part or his?". To me these small discrepancies look like simple rounding errors.

Comment: But 81.45 + 0.72 = 82.17 which is not equal to 82.18, I don't see where the rounding comes in? Also, how did he get his PVs from? What discount factor did he use to acquire them? And, why is my discount factor incorrect?

Comment: If someone tells you 81.45 this means it could be between 81.445 and 81.454 and then got rounded to 81.45. The uncertainty is 0.009. Same applies to 0.72. The two uncertainties add up to something much bigger than the discrepancy of 0.01 that you see.